# Why can't I cite this patent using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm trying to cite the following patent:

```
@patent{sakuma2016,
 author = {Noritsugu Sakuma, Hidefumi Kishimoto, Akira Kato, Tetsuya Shoji, Dominique Givord, Nora Dempsey, Thomas George Woodcock, Oliver Gutfleisch, Gino Hrkac, Thomas Schrefl},
 title = {Production method of rare earth magnet},
 number = {US9520230B2},
 year = {2016}
}
```

However, when I use `\cite{sakuma2016}`, I get the standard bold text which indicates the citation does not exist.

Does anyone know why this is occurring? I am using biblatex, which I have imported with the following command:

```
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

Comment: have you run biber since adding that entry? check the .blg log for errors

Comment: Author names in the `.bib` file are uspposed to be separated by `and` instead of by `,`.

Comment: @leandriis That did the trick!